# Duplicate signal name in Altair

Tags: python, altair

Can someone please explain why this does not work when I uncomment the line but works perfectly when I don't?

```py
time_brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])
role_instance_brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['color'])
role_instance_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=[ROLE_INSTANCE])

color_condition = alt.condition(
    role_instance_selection,
    alt.Color(f'{ROLE_INSTANCE}:N', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20', domain=rolling.index.get_level_values(ROLE_INSTANCE).unique().tolist())).legend(orient="left"),
    alt.value('lightgray')
)

base_chart = alt.Chart(rolling.reset_index(), width=1200).add_params(
  time_brush
)

by_role_instance = base_chart.mark_bar().encode(
  x=alt.X(f'{TIME}:T', title='Time'),
  y=alt.Y(f'mean({AVG_DURATION}):Q', title='Mean duration (s)'),
  color=color_condition
).add_params(
  role_instance_brush,
  role_instance_selection
)

by_activity_base = base_chart.transform_filter(
  time_brush
).transform_aggregate(
  agg_val=f"mean({AVG_DURATION})",
  med_val=f"median({AVG_DURATION})",
  max_val=f"max({AVG_DURATION})",
  groupby=[ACTIVITY],
).transform_window(
    rank='row_number()',
    sort=[alt.SortField(AVG_DURATION, order="descending")],
).transform_calculate(
    act_name=f"datum.rank < 10 ? datum.{ACTIVITY} : 'All Others'"
).encode(
  y=alt.Y('act_name:N', title=None).sort(op="mean", field='agg_val', order="descending")
)

mean_by_activity = by_activity_base.mark_bar().encode(
  x=alt.X('agg_val:Q', title='Duration (s)', aggregate="mean", scale=alt.Scale(domainMin=0))
)

med_by_activity = by_activity_base.mark_bar(color = 'blue').encode(
  x=alt.X('med_val:Q', title='Duration (s)', aggregate="mean", scale=alt.Scale(domainMin=0)),
)

max_by_activity = by_activity_base.mark_bar(color = 'red').encode(
  x=alt.X('max_val:Q', title='Duration (s)', aggregate="mean", scale=alt.Scale(domainMin=0)),
)

by_activity = (max_by_activity + mean_by_activity) # This works well
# by_activity = (max_by_activity + mean_by_activity + med_by_activity) # THIS SAYS DUPLICATE SIGNAL

by_role_instance & by_activity
```

Comment: That error usually means that you have `add_params` of the same parameter happening multiple times. If you can create a [mre], it is possible that someone can troubleshoot and help further